# Excel how to summarise a row of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set that captures time booked to a phase of a project, weekly by staff.

How do I  summarise the data so that it shows the time booked to a phase of a project **by month**?

Example data set:

[image]

What my pivot table ends up looking like:

[image]

Ideally I would like to be quite generic as would like to produce a template.

How do I get it to look like this?
[image]

Comment: What is your actual problem? Please [edit] and be explicit in the question.

Comment: Hi David - I have updated, is it clearer now?

Comment: I think you want to group your dates. Right-Click on the date column and look for groups...

Comment: Unfortunately when right-clicking their is no option to group.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted to do using a Power Query and Pivot Tool, and then "unpivoting" the columns with the dates in. This transposed them to rows and then I was able to use the group function and the analysis required. 
If you have a similar problem and/ or are trying to transpose columns into rows, this video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?=JMrfbv2h7p8&list=PLmHVyfmcRKyyKV86N7i0q9TfYNN8bBjX-